# RavenDB alternate to reduce the budget

Tags: nosql, ravendb, commercial-application

My company is using RavenDB for 8 years. But now we are trying to replace RavenDB as it is pricier option. Around AUD 3800 we have to pay for it annually. We are trying to reduce this cost. Can you suggest something free better and robust?
How about Redis/DynamoDB or CouchDB?
Do they come free for commercial use?

Answer (score 2):

But why? With the latest version, RavenDB has now a **[Free](https://ravendb.net/buy) Community License**,
offering quite a nice set of features, including Backups, Security, Clustering and more.

In addition to being fully transactional - providing **full ACID compliance** throughout the database and throughout the Database Cluster, their storage engine is very robust.

Comment: We are on professional license of ravendb. See the pricing model comparison - https://ravendb.net/buy

we need more RAM as our product has 10,000 users.